# New velocity after circle collision

Tags: c++, collision, geometry

On a circular billiard-table, the billiard-ball collides with the boundary of that table with some velocity v1. This collision is detected as follows:

```
double s = sqrt( (p.x-a)*(p.x-a) + (p.y-b)*(p.y-b) );
if (s<r)        // point lies inside circle
                    // do nothing
else if (s==r)  // point lies on circle
                    // calculate new velocity
else if (s>r)   // point lies outside circle 
                    // move point back onto circle (I already have that part)
                    // calculate new velocity
```

Now how can the *new velocity v2 after the collision* be calculated, such that *angle of incidence = angle of reflection* (elastic collision)?

PS: The billiard-ball is represented by a point p(x,y) with a velocity-vector v(x,y). The simulation is *without friction*.

Comment: This question does not seem to be C++-specific. In fact, it seems more like a math-question than a programming question.

Comment: Where's your initial velocity and how are you representing it?

Comment: Something like `v_new = coeff*(v_old - 2*dot(v_old, boundary_normal)*boundary_normal);` for some seriously simplified physics?

Comment: That's a mechanics question, and it would help if you stated what each symbol represents. Also, are the table boundaries aligned along X and Y or not? Do they absorb any energy or are they perfectly elastic? In the simplest case you flip Vx or Vy respectively and calculate the new magnitude. Which should be the same as the one before the collision...

Comment: Basic physics - see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution

Comment: @Tim I updated the question, velocity its just a vector.

Comment: @Bart The simulation is frictionless. Could you explain how to find coeff and boundary_normal please?

Comment: The boundary normal is simply the (inward pointing) normal of the circular billiards table at the point of impact. If you don't care about accuracy, then coeff is simply a fudged factor between 0 and 1. Otherwise it is what Paul hints at (still between 0 and 1).

Comment: @juanchopanza It's a circle in 2D, how would it be axis-aligned, it's not rotated if that's what you mean. Perfectly elastic collision. Flipping vx or vy works for a rectangle, not for a circle. I've tried that.

Comment: The circle's contact with the edge is on a tangent to the circle, so the radius from centre of mass of the circle (the centre) is perpendicular to the edge. So the problem is the same as if you had a point. Think of a point as a circle of infinitely small radius. Scaling the radius up shouldn't change the dynamics.

Comment: You didn't factor in the velocity of equilibrium for your rail.  it will only be elastic on a pool table if the speed at which the ball hits the rail at the equilibrium velocity.  If it's rolling too fast for a kick shot (against a rail), the ball angle of reflection will be less than the angle of incidence.  If it's rolling too slow, the angle of reflection will be more than the angle of reflection.  Every rail is different though.  :-)  Also what about English.  To make this more correct, we need to have the velocity of spin and it's axis of rotation for the English.  Great Question!

Comment: and the angle of incidence changes exponentially depending on the initial angle of hitting the rail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're making some simple (game-like) billiards simulation you could use something like:

```
v_new = coeff*(v_old - 2*dot(v_old, boundary_normal)*boundary_normal);
```

Here `v_old` is your current velocity vector and `boundary_normal` is the inward pointing normal of your circular billiards table at the point of impact. If you know the center `c` of your circular table and you have the point of impact `p` then the normal is simply `normalize(c-p)`. That is, the normalized vector you obtain when subtracting `p` from `c`.

Now I have taken `coeff` to be a fudge factor between 0 (no velocity at all anymore after impact) and 1 (same velocity after impact). You can make this more physically plausible by determining a correct coefficient of restitution.

In the end all the formula above is, is simple [reflection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Reflection.html) as you might have seen in a basic ray tracer for example. As said, it's a fairly crude abstraction from an accurate physics simulation, but will most likely do the job.

Comment: I updated my question to show the results I got with your formula. There seems to be a mistake in there?

Comment: Your normal is wrong. I wrote normalize(c-p). So your normal can never have a length of 250. You need to normalize it.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I forgot that. So now it works for the case stated in my first question-update. However, for other cases, the velocity increases (see second update).

Comment: What do you get? What is your coeff? Your normals are still wrong. How do you normalize?

Comment: I added my source-code to my question (at the bottom). Could you have a look at what is wrong? I used 1 for the coefficient to get the same velocity after the impact as before the impact.

Comment: The formula can be derived without too much trouble by just drawing out the geometric representation of the vectors in question.  I've had to deduce it myself a few times for interviews where the net isn't available...

Comment: You are using your normalized n.x again when normalizing n.y

Comment: Great. Perhaps you can now clean-up the question to the essentials. Then it might be useful again to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, this is a mechanics question.
Have a look at the [momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum) definition.
What you want in particular, is covered in the section *elastic collisions*.