# Billiards game collision

Tags: collision-detection, pygame

I've choice to write a billiard game for class. All runs ok but I would like to improve realism to ball collisions.

For each ball I have a pygame rectangle, that means, ball center, ball diameter and position in game. And also a velocity vector (u_x, u_y).

At this time I check collision with colliderect, but I can change it measuring center balls distances.

I have read about Conservation of momentum equations but this not have ball positions in consideration. Is not the same two ball frontal impact than a lateral impact.

Someone can help to me in **formula for new ball velocities after collision considering ball position at the impact moment**. Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429315/new-velocity-after-circle-collision/8429777#8429777

Comment: @bart, thanks, but I dont understant `dot`, and `boundary_normal`. It is easy for you write python formula from this link?

Comment: `dot` refers to the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) and `boundary_normal` is the normal vector at the point of impact.

Comment: oh! nice. I know how to calculate dot product, but, how can I take normal vector from my data? Thanks about your help, bart.

Comment: bart, is a classical round billiard ball. You have center (x,y) and diameter (d) for both balls.

Comment: Actually, the collision section [here](http://archive.ncsa.illinois.edu/Classes/MATH198/townsend/math.html) might help you out for ball-ball collisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `euclid` will help. It contains a vector class, that has normal(), dot(), etc... http://partiallydisassembled.net/euclid.html ( You can copy the module into your project folder, without needing to install. )

For the formulas, check : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/7901/6776 , or http://archive.ncsa.illinois.edu/Classes/MATH198/townsend/math.html#COLLISION

Note: the more complicated your physics become, the more you need to use a physics engine, such as [enter link description here][pymunk] or ODE. But, it is a good learning experience.