# Calculating the angle on a bouncing back ball

Tags: android, game-physics, trigonometry

I have been working on a game and am having some problems with the bouncing effect. I have searched on the Internet for different resources but have not found the correct way of doing it.

I wonder if there is some way to calculate the degrees or the angle that the ball will bounce back after hitting a wall.

Exampel, the ball is moving at a specific angle, I am wondering how to calculate the angle when I bounce

```
bollX += bollspeed*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)); 
bollY += bollspeed*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angel));
```

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the walls are all vertical or horizontal, you could just reverse the x or the y velocity, depending on which wall you hit.

Comment: They are all vertical and horizontal. The calculation I try to find out is if the ball is moving 315 degrees for exampel and bounce on the horizontal(90degrees) wall it should bounce back in 275 degrees.

Comment: i think you wil have an easier time if you use vector math. You can look [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/61069-bounce-vector/) for a good explanation how it is done.

Comment: I am trying with atan2, see if I can make 4 different calculations depending on what side of the wall is hit,,, ?

Comment: I have answered [a related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429315/new-velocity-after-circle-collision/8429777#8429777). Perhaps that's helpful to you. Things will be far easier to express with vector math as Renard suggests. All you need is a normal vector for the surface you're colliding against.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is way simpler than you are making it. You don't actually need to worry about angles at all, just think about it in terms of components. When the ball hits something on a vertical side, the x component of its velocity is flipped. When the ball hits something on a horizontal side, the y component of its velocity is flipped.

For example, pseudocode for your collision handling might look something like this:

```
if (hits on left or right side of brick)
    ball.velocity.x = -ball.velocity.x;
else if (hits on top or bottom side of brick)
    ball.velocity.y = -ball.velocity.y;
endif
```

From your code provided, I can't exactly tell if you have some sort of velocity components like this. To represent your velocity, you must either have an angle and a magnitude, or an x and y component. If you chose the former when designing your game, I strongly suggest switching over to components because it makes all of the math along the way much easier because you'll just end up converting everything to components anyways.

Note that this answer is assuming you only bounce exactly horizontally or vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You should know the unit normal vector "n" which is perpendicular vector to edge line on which ball touch and bounce back and **(n · n)**=1.

If you say unit normal vector **n** and your velocity vector **v** then
your new velocity vector will be,
**v<sub>new</sub>** = **v** - 2**(v · n)n**, where bold characters represent vectors and "**·**" represents dot product .

Below link is visual representation of this calculation, which may give better insight
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/Reflection2_751.gif